# Recursion returns a list, not of its own elements, but of others

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I have documents that are based on others, through recursion, I find documents that refer to what they are based on, the problem is that they are all duplicated into one, it does not work correctly

not the correct variant

[image]

I want to get this

[image]

In the code, the main thing that I transfer is the Type of the document and the List of child elements

```
   public async Task<List<DocumentTreeItem>> FillRecursionTree(Guid documentId, string documentPresentationName, List<DocumentTreeItem> treeItems, Type documentType)
        {
            await FillRecursionTree(documentId, documentPresentationName, treeItems, documentType);
         
            return treeItems;

            async Task FillRecursionTree(Guid childrenId, string childrenIdDocumentPresentationName, List<DocumentTreeItem> childrenIdTreeItems, Type childrenIdDocumentType)
            {

                var currentNode = new DocumentTreeItem(documentPresentationName, childrenIdDocumentType, childrenIdTreeItems)
                {
                    Id = childrenId,
                    DocumentPresentationName = childrenIdDocumentPresentationName,
                    TypeDocument = childrenIdDocumentType
                };
                childrenIdTreeItems.Add(currentNode);


                var customerInvoices = await GetBaseCustomerInvoiceDocuments(childrenId);
                foreach (var customerInvoice in customerInvoices)
                {
                    childrenIdDocumentType = customerInvoice.GetType();
                    await FillRecursionTree(customerInvoice.Id, customerInvoice.DocumentPresentationName, **currentNode.Childrens,** childrenIdDocumentType);
                }
            }
        }
```

if i think correctly i need to add elements to the root element but how do i do it so i don't get then all the elements again if they don't fit

currentNode.Childrens <-
How can I pass from the main document only the required array of child elements, and not all at once, where everything falls.
Maybe I'm wrong and the problem is in the second one.

This is the type in which I keep everything, there is a children's letter in which all the documents made on its basis are recorded.

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string? DocumentPresentationName { get; set; }
public Type TypeDocument { get; set; }

public List<DocumentTreeItem> Childrens { get; set; } = new List<DocumentTreeItem>();

public DocumentTreeItem(string documentPresentationName, Type typeDocument, List<DocumentTreeItem> children = null)
{
    DocumentPresentationName = documentPresentationName;
    TypeDocument = typeDocument;
    if (children != null)
        Children.AddRange(children);
}

public List<DocumentTreeItem> Children
{
    get
    {
        return Childrens;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed the entire array of elements of the root, and did not create a new one

```
 var currentNode = new DocumentTreeItem(documentPresentationName, childrenIdDocumentType, **new List<DocumentTreeItem>()**)
                {
                    Id = childrenId,
                    DocumentPresentationName = childrenIdDocumentPresentationName,
                    TypeDocument = childrenIdDocumentType
                };
```